# C# Parsing JSON Object

Tags: c#, json

I am wondering if we can take some parts inside a JSON string and print it out. I have a JSON string and I only want to take some specific things in it.
My JSON string:

```
{
"A": {
   "a1":[
      {
         "a11": {
              "a111": "something1",
              "a112": "something2"
          },
         "a12": [
             {
                "a121": "something1",
                "a122": "something2"
             },
             {
                "a211": "something1",
                "a212": "soemthing2"
             }
           ]
       ]
  },
 "B": {
   "b1":[
      {
         "b11": {
              "b111": "something1",
              "b112": "something2"
          },
         "b12": [
             {
                "b121": "something1",
                "b122": "something2"
             },
             {
                "b211": "something1",
                "b212": "soemthing2"
             }
           ]
       }
    ]
   }
 }
```

I only want to print out: **b121 is something1**. How can I do it in C#?

Comment: Yes, you can do this reasonably easily with Json.NET. Parse it as a `JObject` and then write code to "explore" the object  potentially with `JObject.Descendants`. However, you're unlikely to get help here without showing *some* effort to try this yourself - Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, and we expect questions to show what the person asking has already tried before asking the question. It's more productive to correct an attempt at a solution than to just provide the solution directly.

Comment: Also your json is not valid. Its really prudent when asking a question to make sure your information is as correct as possible, you have added as much information as you can so we can clearly understand the problem, where you are at, and the difficulties you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your JSON example has some problems so I'll give an example using this part as the JSON file.

```
{
"B": {
   "b1":
      {
         "b11": {
              "b111": "something1",
              "b112": "something2"
          },
         "b12": [
             {
                "b121": "something1",
                "b122": "something2"
             },
             {
                "b211": "something1",
                "b212": "soemthing2"
             }
           ]
       }
  }
}
```

You can access to a specific part like this using [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/):

```
var jsonData = File.ReadAllText(@"\test.json");

dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);

// print out a specific part
Console.WriteLine(jsonObject.B.b1.b11.b111);
```